# What's to Search for in a VM Provider When Increased Resiliency is Sought for But not Necessarily HA Compliance?

Tags: virtual-machines

I am lost on how to search for a VM Provider beyond a few I found that boasts increased resiliency is commanded but not "total HA"?

My situation is as follows...

I am deaf and blind individual thus it's impossible for me to say set an alert say like PushOver to alert me while I am asleep since *literally cannot hear a thing* while sleeping. Since my hearing is in a such an impaired state (hence why I am deaf and blind since my sight is as well). Thus I am really looking for a provider who can simply auto migrate and reboot the VM onto a healthy node. Instead of being concerned of leaving my users without service for hours on end should the host node fails in say 3 in the morning.

May someone help me this sorta of thing out? Cause as I said I don't know how to search for a "in between" option between your usual Vultr, Linode, etc options to a "true HA" provider.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: All the cloud services do this (AWS, Google, Azure). Is there a reason why you do not consider them?

Comment: No they don't, if you look at Vultr, Linode, etc they aren't more than a VPS provider in all honestly. As for those ones, they are not in comsumer price ranges. Of course I am expecting to pay somewhat more than a $3 to $5/GB VPS but at the same time the budgetary requirements is not adequate for true HA as those guys.

Comment: I said cloud services, not VPS providers like those you named. The feature you are asking for is baseline for a cloud service, and though they may misuse the term for marketing, they are absolutely not cloud services without it.

Comment: Exactly, those are also cloud providers too, they do market themselves as cloud. Because technically anything in a data center is indeed a cloud. So this term had gone from meaning "resiliency" to a "buzzword" in marketing. I hope this explains why I am so conflicted on why I am having difficulties pinning down what I need. At a reasonable budget for me.

Comment: I guess you mean `auto scaling` when you write `true HA`? AWS calls it [auto scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html), Linode calls it [nodebalancers](https://www.linode.com/products/nodebalancers/) and vultr calls it [load balancers](https://www.vultr.com/products/load-balancers/).

Comment: As per question I means in relation rebooting me onto a working node. The issue as stated is how to search for cloud providers who provides this apart from those whose don't. I am not quite sure what one would call this when you don't want HA but you still want your VM back up and running in minutes instead of hours.

Comment: You should not expect to pay "consumer price ranges" for a business-grade service.  Consumer networking is off-topic.

Comment: A VPS is still considered business grade in the intent of this. Many people rent VPSes from SMBs and such. Not exclusive to AWS/GCP/etc.